# How to set a stockpile for only empty barrels?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm currently on a v40.24 of Dwarf Fortress, and I'm lost on all the possibilities on the **stockpiles** menus...

My brewer is at the top level of my fortress, near the seeds and near my farm. But my carpenter is 8 levels below, so my brewer need to go get those empty barrels pretty far from his store. 
So, I would love to make a stockpile of empty barrels, just next to him.

So far, I would have think that this options was in *Furniture/Siege Ammo -> Type*, and there would be the *Barrel* option, but there isn't !

So: **How could I make a stockpile only of empty barrels ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Barrels are indeed found under Furniture/Siege Ammo -> Type, but on the second page. Scroll all the way to the bottom of the first page to open the second page, as in the screenshot below.

[image: Stockpile settings with barrels highlighted]